How to add a commit describing a git filter-repo --path-rename?
I would like to rename files and folders in Git, keeping the commit history with the new name. git filter-repo --path-rename almost does what I need, except that I'd like have a commit describing the rename.
Since git filter-repo --path-rename doesn't add such a commit, I thought of first doing the git filter-repo --path-rename and then doing a git commit on the renamed files. However, Git doesn't seem to (as far I can tell) allow me to stage unchanged files, so I can't really do a git commit on the renamed files.
I'm going to next try using a git-filter-repo filename callback to see it can be used to add a new commit. But I thought I'd also ask if anyone knows how to have git filter-repo --path-rename add a commit describing the rename?

Ehm, git filter-repo does not keep the commit history, it rewrites it (i.e. throws it away and creates it anew). So you commit "describing the rename" would not describe a rename, because the rename is not visible in your repository (all commits are replaced with rewritten commits). If you want a single commit to rename your files, simply rename them (git mv) and then commit.

One of the points of using git-filter-repo is to make it look like it was always that way. If you want a rename commit you may not even need git-filter-repo.

I guess it's unclear what your goal is here. I assume you already know you can rename the files now with a new commit, and then you don't need to rewrite anything, but obviously you don't want that since you asked the question. But you also don't want to pretend the files always had the new name, since you also wouldn't have asked the question. So, do you want to pretend that the files are being renamed earlier than they actually were? (Since otherwise the rename would be right now...)

The problem is that I want to rename a file, both (1) adding a commit to the files' commit history and (2) keeping the file's commit history with the new name.  git mv does (1) but not (2), and git filter-repo --path-rename does (2) but not (1).

Ah. In that case, I predict you're about to jump into a rabbit hole of (pleasure?) reading about the fact that Git does not store file renames in the history.

@TTT I'm quite aware of the rabbit hole in which Git doesn't store file renames in its commit history. :) The app I'm working on is a tool that moves files with change history from an SCM that does track renames to Git.  So, I need (would like) to emulate the tracking of renames in Git as best I can.

What is the purpose of retaining the old names?

@Schwern I don't understand your question. filter-repo --path-rename doesn't retain the old names; rather it moves (by rewriting the commit history) the commit history from the files with the old names to the files with the new names.  This is what the SCM we're moving from does on  file renames, except that the old SCM also adds an entry to the history describing the each rename.  I would the like the Git commit history to mirror the old SCM's change history (to the best extent I can accomplish).


I would like to rename files and folders in Git, keeping the commit history with the new name. git filter-repo --path-rename almost does what I need, except that I'd like have a commit describing the rename.

You could add an empty commit, git commit --allow-empty, describing the change. But this wouldn't make Git aware there was a rename, just any humans who happen to find that commit. Not very useful.
And, as has been pointed out in the comments, this defeats the point of git filter-repo which makes it look like the file was named that way through all history. If you want people aware there was a rename, you might as well do a git mv.
But we get the real problem in the comments...

The problem is that I want to rename a file, both (1) adding a commit to the files' commit history and (2) keeping the file's commit history with the new name. git mv does (1) but not (2), and git filter-repo --path-rename does (2) but not (1).
The app I'm working on is a tool that moves files with change history from an SCM that does track renames to Git. So, I need (would like) to emulate the tracking of renames in Git as best I can.

I'm sorry to say, you're paddling upstream. As you know, Git does not store renames. In Git, a file has two parts. Its content stored as a blob object, and its path and permissions stored as a tree object. Git treats these as two separate things. Trying to retain all the features of your previous system is an anti-pattern. You'll have to adapt to Git's heuristics.
One thing that helps the heuristics is to only rename the files in one commit, and edit them in another. Change the name, then change the content. Avoid changing both the name and content in one commit.
Typically renames are consequential for merges and code archeology like git blame and git log and git diff. Git has many heuristics to find renames, and these are configurable.
The default ort merge strategy will look for renames. You can configure this with merge.renames (on by default), merge.directoryRenames (defaults to cause a conflict), and merge.renameLimit.
git-diff has similar options.
git-log and git-blame have -C and -M to put more effort into finding copies. Unfortunately these lack config options. For a single file there is log.follow. I use aliases...
# Ignore whitespace, find copies and moves harder, show the line number of the original commit
archeology = blame -w -C -M -n

# Find copies and moves, and follow the renames of individual files.
logfile = log --follow -C -M


This "answer" doesn't really answer my question, but rather raises concerns on why I shouldn't being doing what I asked.  This in itself can be useful, and I appreciate such discussion.  However. I'm aware of many (most) of the concerns raised and have carefully considered them.  So, I'm still looking for an answer to my original question.

@GeoffAlexander If the question is "how can I make Git track renames" the short answer is "you can't", this answer is the long answer. If you told us why you want to make Git track renames, we could get creative. You need to track renames exactly because...?

My question isn't "how can I make Git track renames", as I already know that Git doesn't track renames.  My question is "How can I add have git filter-repo --path-rename add a commit history entry to the renamed file(s).  If multiple files are renamed by a single git filter-repo --path-rename command, I would like the same commit history entry to be added to each renamed  file's commit history.  I'm open to having the commit history entry added as part of the git filter-repo --path-rename command or by a separate command.

In addition, I need to be able to specify the added commit history entry's content (author, change date/time, committer, commit date/time, and message).  Adding an commit history entry as part of the git filter-repo --path-rename command is single additional change to the commit history in addition to the other commit history changes the command already does.  Since git filter-repo --path-rename works by rewriting the commit history, I was thinking (hoping) that it would be possible to have it an commit history entry.

@GeoffAlexander "How can I add have git filter-repo --path-rename add a commit history...?" You can't, there's no such concept in Git (you can make a meaningless-to-Git empty commit), and we've explained why the question almost doesn't make sense. "I would like the same commit history entry to be added to each renamed file's commit history." Files don't have their own commit history in Git, every commit is a complete snapshot. What SCM are you coming from? And, again, if you tell us what you need this for we might be able to provide a solution that works in Git.

Sorry for delay in responding; I got pulled off on something else.  Based on the responses I received (and my own investigation), I agree that it's not possible to do what I asked.  Thanks to everyone that responded.
I'm now looking whether it's possible to use git filter-repo --commit-callback to add one or mores file changes to an existing commit. So far, I've been able to append a new FileChange to commit.files_changes in the commit callback , but this doesn't seem to actually add the file change to the commit in the rewritten commit history.
